# How to send voip push notification from node js? I can send voip push from curl but not node

Tags: ios, node.js, voip

I am making ios app using voip push notification.
I want to send voip push notification from node js, but not well.

I read this tutorial [CallKit iOS Swift Tutorial for VoIP Apps (Super Easy)](https://websitebeaver.com/callkit-swift-tutorial-super-easy) and I made ios app using voip push.
I can send voip push from curl command.

```sh
curl -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}' --http2 --cert chara.pem:passphase https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/ede0d5e78f771d5916345aa48bd098e86aeab40b5e7d985fb9c74586d1a5a681
```

`node index.js`

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const bundleID = 'com.swiswiswift.CharacterAlarm'
    const deviceToken = 'ede0d5e78f771d5916345aa48bd098e86aeab40b5e7d985fb9c74586d1a5a681'

    const headers = {
      'apns-topic': bundleID
    };

    const options = {
      protocol: 'https:',
      method: 'POST',
      hostname: 'api.push.apple.com',
      path: '/3/device/' + deviceToken,
      headers: headers,
      cert: fs.readFileSync('chara.pem'),
      passphrase: "passphrase"
    };

    const client = http2.connect('api.push.apple.com')
    const req = client.request(options)
    req.setEncoding('utf8')

    req.on('response', (headers, flags) => {
      console.log(headers)
    });

    let data = ''
    req.on('data', (d) => data += d)
    req.on('end', () => client.destroy())
    req.end()
}

exports.handler('local-test')
```

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  ':status': 405,
  'apns-id': 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx' }
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing. Did you manage to make it ?

Comment: First of all, If you are trying to use Voip Push for other than sending calls, it won't work, and will block eventually from iOS 13, Xcode 11 onwards. Any way VOIP push from Nodejs is still on the topic , check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633188/apns-apple-push-notification-service-with-node-js

Comment: I getting  "* Connection #0 to host api.push.apple.com left intact
{"reason":"BadDeviceToken"}* Closing connection 0" when executing the curl command

Answer (score 11):

```
var apn = require("apn");

var deviceToken = "device token";

var service = new apn.Provider({
    cert: '.path to /cert.pem', key:'pat to ./key.pem'
});

    var note = new apn.Notification();


  note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60; // Expires 1 minute from now.
  note.badge = 3;
  note.sound = "ping.aiff";
  note.alert = " You have a new message";
  note.payload = {'messageFrom': 'Rahul test apn'};
  note.topic = "(Bundle_id).voip";
  note.priority = 10;
  note.pushType = "alert";

  service.send(note, deviceToken).then( (err,result) => {
    if(err) return console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    return console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
  });
```

This is a working code for apn voip push

also refer this

https://alexanderpaterson.com/posts/send-ios-push-notifications-with-a-node-backend

Comment: DeviceTokenNotForTopic error occcurs . i gave my app identifier in note.topic

Comment: I think you your phone might have separate tokens for voip and other notifications

Comment: @Ansar add 'voip' at the end of bundle id. like, notification.topic = "yourbundleid.voip".

Answer (score 6):

I'm using a slightly different approach:

If you don't know where to find or how to create the key, keyId and teamID, have a look at [this article](https://rossbulat.medium.com/apple-push-notifications-with-react-native-and-node-js-17cde7b8d065) on Medium. He explains all of this in detail.

```
var apn = require('apn');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const options = {
  token: {
    key: 'APNKey.p8',
    keyId: 'S83SFJIE38',
    teamId: 'JF982KSD6f'
  },
  production: false
};
var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);

// Sending the voip notification
let notification = new apn.Notification();

notification.body = "Hello there!";
notification.topic = "my.bundleid.voip";   // Make sure to append .voip here!
notification.payload = {
  "aps": { "content-available": 1 },
  "handle": "1111111",
  "callerName": "Richard Feynman",
  "uuid": uuidv4()
};

apnProvider.send(notification, deviceToken).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: pls, mentioned that add 'voip' at the end of bundle id. like, notification.topic = "yourbundleid.voip".