# How to create voip push notification from Node.js server

Tags: ios, node.js, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, voip

I want to send voip push to my iOS app when its not active, and I tried to use `apn module` from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152554/how-to-send-voip-push-notification-from-node-js-i-can-send-voip-push-from-curl) but it did not work for me.
I followed official apple docs about voip push [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) but still have some problems to send it from the server.
I also tried to send it trough AWS sns service but got normal push for notification and etc.

What do I do wrong?

Right now my code is :

here I do format for sns item

```
const formatVoipPushNotificationsToSend = (type, header, launchId, sender, to = '', device_token, token) => {
    
    const headers = {
        ':method': 'POST',
        'apns-topic': '************.voip', //application bundle ID
        ':scheme': 'https',
        ':path': `/3/device/${device_token}`,
        'authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
        'apns-push-type': 'voip',
    };

    const aps = {
        alert: {
            title: header,
            body: 'text' || null
        },
        itemId: type,
        from: sender || null,
        to,
        launchId: launchId || null,
        'content-available': 1
    };
    return { aps, headers };
};
```

and then I pass the item here and send it to the app with sns endpoint.

```
const pushNotifications = (item, arn, userId) => {
    const payload = JSON.stringify(item);

    const snsMessage = {};
    snsMessage[SNS_PAYLOAD_KEY] = payload;

    const params = {
        Message: JSON.stringify(snsMessage),
        TargetArn: arn,
        MessageStructure: 'json'
    };

    const eventBody = item.aps.itemId ? {
        [EVENT_TYPES.PUSH_SEND]: item.aps.itemId
    } : {};
    
    AmplitudeService.logEvent(EVENT_TYPES.PUSH_SEND, userId, eventBody);

    return snsClient.publish(params).promise();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a slightly different approach:

```
var apn = require('apn');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const options = {
  token: {
    key: 'APNKey.p8',
    keyId: 'S83SFJIE38',
    teamId: 'JF982KSD6f'
  },
  production: false
};
var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);

// Sending the voip notification
let notification = new apn.Notification();

notification.body = "Hello there!";
notification.topic = "com.myapp.voip";
notification.payload = {
  "aps": { "content-available": 1 },
  "handle": "1111111",
  "callerName": "Richard Feynman",
  "uuid": uuidv4()
};

apnProvider.send(notification, deviceToken).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Do you keep APNKey.p8 file inside the project folder or just pass the name of it? @egor518

Comment: and one more question - do you send it straight away from your server or you use firebase or aws?

Comment: How to use pem or p12 instead of p8 file?